# Change position of numbers on y-axis in core-plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

How can I get the numbers to display on the right side of the axis instead of the left?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tickDirection` property. The possible values are:

```
CPTSignNone     // No offset
CPTSignPositive // Positive offset
CPTSignNegative // Negative offset
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the `axisLabels` or `minorTickAxisLabels` property of `CPTXYAxis` to a custom array of `CPTAxisLabel` objects, you can set the `offset` property of each label object to a sufficiently negative value, and it should slide the labels to the right. Or, if you are letting Core Plot draw the labels by itself by using a `labelingPolicy` of `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic`, there is a `labelOffset` property of the `CPTXYAxis` object that you can again set to a sufficiently negative number.